# Is $\ln (a+bi)$ possible when finding the answers to trigonometric functions?

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

I was doing a problem, namely $\tan (x)= 3$, which I knew had real roots, by Euler's formula.
I got some results in the form: $-i\ln (a+bi)$ where $a$ and $b$ were constants.
However, one of my friends told me that $\ln(x)$ does not hold for complex values, in particular when calculating $\tan (x)$.
I had previously solved $\sin (x) = 2$ and $\cos (x) = 2$, and the values were predictably imaginary and seemed accurate enough (I verified them from Wolfram Alpha). So why should $\tan (x)$ not hold while $sin (x)$ and $ cos (x)$ did?
So I tried a very simple calculation by 2 approaches to see if they matched, namely: $$\cos (x) = \frac 12$$
Here is what I did:

[image: Approach 1]
[image: Approach 2]
[image: Approach 2 continued]
The two approaches matched showing that $ln (x)$ does hold in the complex plane.
 However I am not entirely sure if my working was right. Could anybody verify this for me? And could anybody explain why does it not hold while solving for $tan (x)$ (if it does not hold).
Thanks in advance!

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln+(1%2F2+%2B(i%2F2)sqrt3)

P.S. I am sorry but I could not type all that in mathjax. And please pardon me for my despicable handwriting. This was as good as I could write.

Comment: I think its just going in circles, for finding $-i\ln(\tfrac{1}{2} + i \tfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ you need to repeat your calculation backwards.

Comment: The polar form of a complex number is $z = re^{it}$. Taking the logarithm of this is easy. Note that log is multivalued in the complex numbers, so there are infinite answers to such a question

Comment: Yes, but I used wolfram alpha to compute that part. However it could be that WA computed it by the method specified by you.

Comment: I think that is what he meant when he said that $ln (x)$ does not hold (not work properly) in the complex plane.

Comment: @Kaynex we generally assume the range $-\pi$ to $\pi$, right?

Comment: That's an odd way to say "does not work properly". It works exactly as intended, and gets all the solutions to a question, of which there are infinite. The principal Log(x) does assume a closed range, yes.

Comment: What I meant was that $\ln (x)$ generally produces only 1 unique solution. Sorry if you misunderstood me as I was quite vague.

Comment: Generally, $\text{Log}$ refers to the principle logarithm.

Comment: The thing is $e^{i\theta} = e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)}$, that is $e^{x}$ is many to one. So complex logarithm is one to many, unless we restrict the range for argument.

Comment: But I am still confused about why the results for $\tan (x)$ is invalid (if it actually is)?

Comment: See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm). "Since every nonzero complex number z has infinitely many logarithms,[1] care is required to give such notation an unambiguous meaning."

Comment: you were having problem with $\tan x = 3 $ so why did you bring the $\cos$ and tried nothing about your $\tan$ ? :)

Comment: Your solution is valid, but it begs the question per se. How do we compute this logarithm your answer comes down to? You could've equivalently said $x=\cos^{-1}(1/2)$ when solving $\cos(x)=1/2$, but that doesn't really tell you anything about what $x$ is, does it?

Comment: $$\log z=\log|z|+i\arg(z).$$

Comment: $\tan (x)$ is $\frac {\sin (x)}{\cos (x)}$ so I was trying to prove the two parts of it. And I was quite confused as I received 4 different solutions for $\tan (x)$. And I have a long history of making mistakes.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan As explained in the Wikipedia link as well as samjoe's comment, there will be infinitely many solutions to questions of the form $\sin(x)=a,\cos(x)=b,\tan(x)=c$, as these are periodic functions in the complex plane.

Comment: I completely forgot the periodicity of the trigonometric equations. So, was my friend right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the complex representation of the tangent, the equation reads

$$\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}=\frac{e^{2ix}-1}{e^{2ix}+1}=3i.$$

So

$$e^{2ix}=\frac{1+3i}{1-3i}=\frac{-4+3i}5$$

and

$$x=\frac1{2i}\log\frac{-4+3i}5.$$

As the modulus of the argument is one, the logarithm is purely imaginary and the solutions are real anyway.